# Only output a specific file descriptor using bash

Tags: bash

The following command redirects fd 2 to `/dev/null` is it possible to only output `2`?

```
node ./index.js 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: You want only text on standard error to be outputted? Then redirect fd 1 (standard output) to /dev/null instead.

Comment: @Shawn not exactly you are assuming that there's no other file descriptors open for this process.

Comment: If there are other output file descriptors, redirect the others,different from 2, to /dev/null.

Answer (score 1):

In the classical Unix programming model, there is no way to do this. Programs may instead try to sweep over all possible FDs and attempt to close them:

```
(
  limit=$(ulimit -n)
  # Try to estimate some upper bound if not set
  [ "$limit" = "unlimited" ] && limit=1024
  for ((i=0; i<limit; i++))
  do
    [ "$i" != 2 ] && exec {i}>&-
  done
  exec node ./index.js
)
```

However, most OS have a way to introspect open FDs. For example, Linux lets you do:

```
(
  for fd in "/proc/$BASHPID/fd"/*
  do
    fd="${fd##*/}"
    [ "$fd" != 2 ] && exec {fd}>&-
  done
  exec node ./index.js
)
```

You may wish to keep 0 and 1 open and/or redirected them from/to `/dev/null`, as some programs don't cope well with stdin and stdout being closed.